# Inherit from parent class extending Typegoose and containing static type-specific methods

Tags: typescript, inheritance, mongoose, typescript-generics, typegoose

I am developing a server with TypeScript and Node JS and I am using Typegoose library for mapping classes into MongoDB Documents.

I have the following two classes:

```js
import { prop, getModelForClass, DocumentType, ReturnModelType, Typegoose } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

export default class Mode {
    // ...various attributes
    @prop() name?: string;
    private document?: DocumentType<Mode>;

    public get id(this: Mode): number {
        if (this.document)
            return this.document._id;
        else throw new Error('Looking for id on non-mapped Mode on database');
    }

    private static get model(): ReturnModelType<typeof Mode> {
        return getModelForClass(Mode);
    }

    private static attachDocument(document: DocumentType<Mode> | null): Mode | null {
        const instance: Mode | null = document as Mode | null;
        if (instance && document)
            instance.document = document;
        return instance;
    }
    // other methods...
}
```

```js
import { prop, getModelForClass, DocumentType, ReturnModelType, Typegoose } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

export default class Player {
    // ...various attributes
    @prop() nickname: string;
    private document?: DocumentType<Player>;

    public get id(this: Player): number {
        if (this.document)
            return this.document._id;
        else throw new Error('Looking for id on non-mapped Player on database');
    }

    private static get model(): ReturnModelType<typeof Player> {
        return getModelForClass(Player);
    }

    private static query(document: DocumentType<Player> | null): Player | null {
        const instance: Player | null = document as Player | null;
        if (instance && document)
            instance.document = document;
        return instance;
    }
    // other methods...
}
```

It is easy to notice that there are similarly defined methods: `id()`, `model()` and `attachDocument()`. I need these methods to abstract the behavior of Typegoose and the execution of queries to the rest of the server. Is there a way to define a superclass such that these three methods can be removed from `Mode` and `Player` and inherited from this superclass by them?

I was thinking about something like this:

```js
export default class Model<T> extends Typegoose {
    protected document: DocumentType<T>;

    public get id(this: T): number {
        if (this.document)
            return this.document._id;
        else throw new Error('Looking for id on non-mapped object on database');
    }

    private static get model(): ReturnModelType<typeof T> {
        return getModelForClass(T);
    }

    private static attachDocument(document: DocumentType<T> | null): T | null {
        const instance: T | null = document as T | null;
        if (instance && document)
            instance.document = document;
        return instance;
    }
}
```

```js
export class Player extends Model<Player> { /* ... */ }
export class Mode extends Model<Mode> { /* ... */ }
```

However it does not seem to be feasible since I cannot pass T as a parameter to `getModelForClass()` method. I've seen that it accepts parameters of type `new () => T`, but I have not found any way to properly use this.

Comment: would `getModelForClass(this)` work?

Comment: If you ended up solving this, I'd love to know the soloutoin.

Answer (score -1):

If `get model()` does not need to be a `private static` method you can try this:

```
class Model<T> extends Object {

    public get model(this: T): T {
        return this;
    }
}

class Player extends Model<Player> { }
class Topic extends Model<Topic> { }

const player = new Player();
const topic = new Topic();

console.log(player.model instanceof Player);
console.log(topic.model instanceof Topic)
```